# 2 or more async requests in javascript to load image or do anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous

Single request and response model at one time do not utilizes full network/internet bandwidth, thus resulting in low performance. (benchmark is of half speed utilization)

**how to make this code use 2 or 3 or more async requests instead of one.(ajax)**
or do i need multi threading? and is it possible in javascript?

(**this is for making a video out of an ip** )
every time the image changes on request. and yes i need to be async with multiple fetch requests (not single as i explained above) or you recomend threads?

```
<html>
<head>  <script language="JavaScript">
    // Global vars
    img = 'http://pastebin.com/i/t.gif';
    timeout = 1000;
    next = 0;

    function onLoad( ) {
        setTimeout( 'reloadImage( )', timeout );
    }

    // Reloader
    function reloadImage( ) {
        next = ( new Date( ) ).getTime( ) + timeout;
        document.images.dv.src = img + "?" + next;
    }
    </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
    <img src="img" name="dv" onLoad="onLoad( )">
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
<head>



</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
var canLoad = true;
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = function() {
    canLoad = true;
    console.log("Image reloaded.");
}
var imageUrl = "http://url/snapshot.jpg";
var fps = 2;

container.appendChild(image);

function loadImage() {
    if (canLoad) {
    canLoad = false;
    var str = new Date().getTime();
    image.setAttribute("src", imageUrl + "?" + str);
    console.log("Reloaded now.");
    } else {
    console.log("Can't reload now.");
    }
}

setInterval(loadImage, fps); // 30 fps

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have only one `img`, and yet you want many "threads" to modify it separately?

Comment: @Passerby this is for making a video out of an ip . every time the image changes on request. and yes i need to be async with multiple fetch requests (not single as i explained above) or you recomend threads?

Comment: Videos and asynchronicity don't mix. Either load all of the images before hand, or use synchronous requests.

Comment: @masood Can you explain more clearly? All I can tell from your code is that you'll reload the image every second. And the timeout value is hard-coded. What would you expect, if 2 "requests" run asynchronously?

Comment: @Asad how to use synchronouse requests. can you give some code?

Comment: @Passerby i would expect that multiple fetch requets download images. 1 ,2 ,3 4 . if current viewed is 3, and 2 loads after 3. 2 is discarded. if 4 comes. its viewed. dont know . just an idea

Comment: @masood So you want to download resource 1234 asynchronously, but still display them in a fixed order? Then what's the different from now? You can hard-coded the `timeout` to 500 or even 50 to make things faster.

Comment: @Asad :) read the first line of the question (it answers your comment) timout is irrelevent. its still single request/respone model

Comment: @Passerby sory that was not for Asad. it was for Passerby

Comment: Oh wow. Haven't seen jpeg videos since 1998. This is hardcore old-school!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not actually tested**, and I think it'll very likely to cause a "stack overflow" eventually (if you directly implement it), but you may still give it a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var img="/*url*/";
        var interval=50;
        var pointer=0;
        function showImg(image,idx)
        {
            if(idx<=pointer) return;
            document.body.replaceChild(image,document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);
            pointer=idx;
            preload();
        }
        function preload()
        {
            var cache=null,idx=0;;
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                idx=Date.now()+interval*(i+1);
                cache=new Image();
                cache.onload=(function(ele,idx){return function(){showImg(ele,idx);};})(cache,idx);
                cache.src=img+"?"+idx;
            }
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].onload=preload;
            document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="/*initial url*/";
        };
    })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img  />
  </body>
</html>
```

What it does:

1. When the initial image loads, `preload()` is called;
2. When `preload()` is called, it creates 5 image cache, and each attach its `onload` event to `showImg()`;
3. When `showImg()` is called, it checks whether the current index is behind current `pointer`, and if it does, replace the current image with this new one, and call `preload()`;
4. Back to 2.

If you really going to implement this, increase `interval` and decrease `i<5`. Also, a caching/queuing mechanic to check how many images in cache/queue before loading the next queue would be nice.

Also, notice that I didn't use `getElementById` to get the image, because there will be no stable ID.

Comment: nice, can you please give a complete working code with the html img tag with it

Comment: @masood Added HTML tag and a little change on JS (about the inital load). Sorry I don't have a proper image link to test this. But before I post, I did test the `onload` event mechanic (which is the essence of this code), so it should work.

Comment: Greate!   do you know java ? Iam making same thing in applet. but having problem

Comment: this is to make a video out of an ip cam that gives a new image on each request. http://pastebin.ca/2247885 makes a delay of 3 - 8 
                   seconds no matter what i do. changed thread no. and thread time intervals . debuged the code by system.out.prinlns to see if threads 
                   work. all seems normal. any help?

Comment: @masood I'm so sorry that Java is way out of my knowledge. The only Java I did was a damn small homework, several years ago.